# TextField superposed in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

I initially load a hidden `tableView` with some data and show this when I press a button, simulating a drop down menu.
In the same view, I have a `UIButton` which when pressed, programmatically creates another `UIButton` and a `UITextField`.

The problem is that when I load again, the `tableView` and all the `textField`s and `button`s are superposed.

This is what happens:

[image]

My question is what can I do for keep the `tableView` in front of in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `-addSubview:`, the view is added as the top-most view.
Which is the reason why your newly added `textField`s are appearing above your `tableView`.

The quickest way to solve your issue would be to make the `tableView` the top-most view when you're planning to show it.

Example:

```
[yourTableView setHidden:NO];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourTableView];
```

<sub>*Assuming that `self.view` contains `yourTableView`*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is a cell reusability issue.

If you are adding controls on cells, when they get reused They will keep the textFields which gives you this strange juxtaposition result.

You have to take proper care of removing the textField which makes things more complex.

Solution is to subclass `UITableViewCell` so that you have prototype cell with `textfield` and another one without.